# How to create a certain amount of elements in the function that returns the HTML template?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm making a simple to-do app where users can add tags to each task.

I store the array of task objects that have tags field. When a user adds a task, it first goes to the local storage, and then the page updates the DOM.

This is a function that updates the DOM:

```
function createTaskTemplate(task, index) {
  return `
   <div class="task flex">
     <input type="checkbox" class="check-task" onclick="checkTask(${index})" 
     ${task.done ? 'checked' : ''}>

     <p class="task-text ${task.done ? 'task-checked' : ''}">${task.name}</p>


     // ========= PROBLEM PART ==============


     // *Below I create the ul tag that must append a certain amount of li tags*

     <ul class="tags"></ul>

     // *And here I want to loop over the task's tags, create HTML for them, and put them in the ul created above*

     ${task.tags.forEach((tag, index) =>
       document
         .querySelector('.tags')
         .appendChild((document.createElement('li').textContent = tag[index]))
     )}

     // =====================================
   </div>`;
```

}

I get the error *Uncaught TypeError: document.querySelector(...) is null*. I know that's because this task is not in the DOM at the moment of execution.

How can I solve this? I had an idea of counting the length of the tags array before returning the template and somehow dynamically create the same amount of li tags in the template. But I don't know if it's possible.

Comment: There's no element with the class `tags` in the DOM. That's what the error is telling you.

Comment: `.appendChild((document.createElement('li').textContent = tag[index]))` will also throw an error.